# TryHackMe rooms not showing up on the browser after launching my openvpn service

Tags: linux, openvpn

I am new to tryhackme and i have a free account. I want to use the openvpn service to solve rooms because 1 hour on the attack box isn't enough. After downloading the configurations package and running "sudo openvpn kujen5.ovpn" it is successful, but after starting the room machine and trying to access the url via my browser it just keeps on loading for ages and doesn't show any result when it should do so. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it by turning of the VPN I had running on the host machine aka my windows pc that I use to host the VM. After turned off that VPN service, I had no trouble with loading rooms urls. Hope this help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a free account, the virtual machine won't work, it's only for paid subscribers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you can't be connected with more than one device at the same time. If you have problems with your connection, try to regenerate your Configuration file and change the server. If you are a paid subscriber, try to use one of the VIP Servers that they have, they work best in my experience. If you are still having problems, please provide the response you get after typing in the command of OpenVPN in your terminal.